# How to avoid over tighten or stripping screws with an impact driver?

Tags: screws, powertools

I got an impact driver last month, but I'm still afraid to use it for some stuff because I think I might over tighten the screw to the point of damaging one or both the parts or even strip the thread on plywood or plastic.

There is no torque setting (and from my research impact drivers don't have them), and I've seen it drive a screw deep into plywood and wood.

Can an impact driver be use for every kind of job? Like screwing electrical receptacles or knobs for drawers, for example.

Comment: When the driver starts slowing down hitting harder let off the trigger or get a drill with an adjustable clutch.

Comment: I suggest avoiding using it for putting small screws in, at least until you've got used to it. The value of "small"  will depend on the materials. So initially bolts or screws with big (coarse) threads and proper heads. For unscrewing you can be more confident.